# "languageHints" does not work in Google Vision API (TEXT_DETECTION)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I'm trying to get a response in a specific language.
I found an example of how to do it in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) from Google (imageContext.languageHints)
As a test, I made a request through Postman.
The problem is that the response is returned in a completely different language than the one I specified. So in the request I specify the **Ukrainian** language "uk", and in the answer I receive **Bulgarian** "bg"

I tried specifying the language as well - "languageHints": **["uk-UA"]** but the result is the same

```
POST https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate
    {
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "https://storage.googleapis.com/tmp_storage_pub/Screenshot_1.png"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ],
      "imageContext": {
        "languageHints": ["uk"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

responses:

```
"responses": [
    {
      "textAnnotations": [
        {
          "locale": "bg",
          "description": "EPAШОВА",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
                      
      "fullTextAnnotation": {
        "pages": [
          {
            "property": {
              "detectedLanguages": [
                {
                  "languageCode": "bg",
                  "confidence": 1
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample image to be used on text detection to properly replicate your use case?

Comment: https://storage.googleapis.com/tmp_storage_pub/Screenshot_1.png
1-st letter must be "Є" in Ukrainian (uk), but not the "Е"

Comment: I can confirm that the same issue where API doesn't recognize languageHints. API keeps using english when image text is in russian and language is ru